# Force WebStorm to have absolute path in imports with Nuxt.js

Tags: ecmascript-6, webstorm, nuxt.js

I'm trying to find a way to tell **WebStorm 2019.1.4** to use absolute path in ES6 imports in a **Nuxt** based application. When doing an automatic import in **WebStorm**, I'm getting for example:

```
import GlassPane from '../components/GlassPane'
```

I'd like to have an absolute path (or alias-based path) in imports, as follows:

```
import GlassPane from '~/components/GlassPane'
```

or even:

```
import GlassPane from '/components/GlassPane'
```

Is it possible?

Note there is no **webpack.config.js** file in a **Nuxt** app, but only a **nuxt.config.js** that wraps it.

Answer (score 2):

Resolving webpack aliases in Nuxt projects is not currently supported, please vote for [WEB-32614](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32614) to be notified on any progress with it.

as a workaround, you can create your own dummy webpack config with your aliases defined, like it's suggested in https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2936#issuecomment-369987598:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    // for WebStorm
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname),
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname)
    }
  }
};
```